# SQLite openOrCreateDatabase unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to learn sqlite for android.
I created an Helper class which should open my DB and do whatever an helper class does.

My problem is that I can't even open the database couse of this error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

This is my relevant code of the DatabaseHelper class, the error is in openOrCreateDatabase line:

```
public class DatabaseHelper<T> implements IDatabaseHelper{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
private static String DATABASE_PATH = "";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static SQLiteDatabase database;
private static Context ctx;

//constructor
public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    ctx = context;
    DATABASE_PATH = ctx.getFilesDir().getPath();
}

//apertura database
public boolean OpenDB() {
    //try{
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null, null);
    return true;
    }
```

It's all sorrounded by try catch but the problem is still that it can't open my database. here is the Stack Trace.

```
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'myDatabase.db'.
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:717)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at personal.pier.weightwatcher.Utils.DatabaseHelper.OpenDB(DatabaseHelper.java:85)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at personal.pier.weightwatcher.Activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:22)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
11-05 17:27:35.410 16641-16641/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: personal.pier.weightwatcher, PID: 16641
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{personal.pier.weightwatcher/personal.pier.weightwatcher.Activities.SplashScreenActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:717)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at personal.pier.weightwatcher.Utils.DatabaseHelper.OpenDB(DatabaseHelper.java:85)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at personal.pier.weightwatcher.Activities.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:22)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
11-05 17:27:35.411 16641-16641/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I can't really find out a solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advice

PS: i'm not extending SQLiteOpenHelper on porpouse, because I want more control on operations since i'm trying to use only one helper for all of my classes.

Comment: give it a full path in your filesystem

Comment: @pskink thanks for the reply, how should i do it? isn't enough the getfilesdir().getpath()?

Comment: you are calling `openOrCreateDatabase` with `DATABASE_NAME` which is simply "myDatabase.db", not something like "/full/path/to/my/database.db"

Comment: @pskink i'm sleeping.. one hour wasted because i supposed i was already doing path + dbname.. thanks a lot you saved my day! if you add a reply i will set it as the correct one :)

Comment: more coffee man, more coffee...

Comment: @pskink ahahahah yes, need it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when calling `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase` the first parameter (`String path`) should be a full path to the file system, make it from `getFilesDir()` or similar call

Answer (score 0):

You should call the super on DatabaseHelper constructor.

```
//constructor
public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    ctx = context;
    DATABASE_PATH = ctx.getFilesDir().getPath();
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying fast, i'm getting error on this, i should add something to my class for using the super? i get "Object() in object cannot be applied to"

Comment: I guess you should extends SQLiteOpenHelper, see this example: [link](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/packages/SettingsProvider/src/com/android/providers/settings/DatabaseHelper.java.shtml)

Comment: nope, i wrote it in the "PS" in the end, i don't wanna extend SQLiteOpenHelper because i want to use one helper class for all my entities, so i need more control. The comment from @pskink solved this, i was simply sleeping while i wrote the code. thanks anyway for the answer! :)

Comment: Oops, sorry! My bad :)